# In php Instead of downloading csv file it gets open in the browser

Tags: php, download, force-download

I'm trying to download a CSV file through the browser. The script is partially working, because so far I managed to display the CSV on screen, but the download is not starting.

Here is what i tried so far:

```
if(isset($currency)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=Pricelogs.csv");
    ob_clean();
    $filename = "/tmp/".uniqid().".csv";
    exportCSVFile($filename, $currency, $country, $provider);
    readfile($filename);
    //unlink("'".$filename."'");
} else {
    echo "ERR_USERNAME_PASSWORD";
    exit();
}
```

I had already read all questions of this type from FAQ & also tried but it gets open on browser only,instead of downloading.
I had also used header with single quotes.
I also tried  `header("Content-Type: text/csv");`
Also:

```
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT your CSV file URL, it will display in browser in place of force browser to download. You can open it in iframe in your site.

http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=www.yoursite.com/filename.csv

Comment: Yas alternative is good one as for now,as i had tried everything else..Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: @PankajDadure this seems to be not working now. Any other possible way to preview CSV files

Answer (score 1):

I usually just do:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_csv_filename.csv");

// print CSV lines here

exit();
```

Comment: Actually i also use to work in same manner but know as i mentioned instead of prompting for download,it just simply gets displayed on the browser.
Also i tried it on all mazor browser,thinking,there might be issue on just a certain browser.

Aslo i added this line in .htaccess file:AddType application/octet-stream csv

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you this combination is working for me:

```
$bom = chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF);
header("Content-type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print $bom . $data;
exit;
```

If I were you, I would first test this plainly (outside of all your buffering), first see that you manage to make this work, and only then test it in your specific set up.

Comment: :Thanks for your suggestion DannyB but I had already worked on it by dividing into single modules i.e plainly,but all contents just gets displayed on browser only.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename.csv\";" );

print $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

For large files you need to get your output buffer started

add : `ob_start();`  at the start

`ob_clean();`  at the end of you file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).